# split txt file line by line and create from each line a txt file

Tags: file, batch-file, split, lines, createfile

I need a batch script which splits a file with 4 lines and creates from those 4 lines 4 txt files.

Looks like this: test.txt

```
line 1
line 2
line 3
line 4
```

--> every line should be outputted in an other txt file.

Thanks guys, Anita

Comment: every line should be printed in a file with a same name?

Answer (score 2):

```dos
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    set "inputFile=test.txt"
    for %%z in ("%inputFile%") do if %%~zz gtr 0 (
        set "lineNumber=1000000000"
        for /f "delims=" %%a in ('
            findstr /n "^" "%inputFile%"
        ') do (
            set "line=%%a" & set /a "lineNumber+=1" 
            setlocal enabledelayedexpansion 
            >"%%~fz.!lineNumber:~-9!" (echo(!line:*:=!)
            endlocal
        )
    )
```

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT**: I simplified the code a little...

```
@echo off

for /F "tokens=1* delims=:" %%a in ('findstr /N "^" test.txt') do (
   > file%%a.txt echo(%%b
)
```

If a line in the file start with colon, this solution will eliminate the colon. This problem may be fixed, if needed.

Comment: why not simply echo each line instead of using SET /P?

Comment: @dbenham: Because using `set /P` the line can be enclosed in quotes. This way, if the line have special characters, like `<|>&`, they are correctly copied...

Comment: But you don't have to worry about escaping or quoting poison characters when expanding FOR variables.

Comment: Ops! I am over-biased by the frequent use of Delayed Expansion! `;)` I modified the code...

Comment: You should use `echo(%%b` because the line might be empty or nothing but white space.

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off
set "filen=c:\file.txt"

for /f "usebackq tokens=* delims=" %%a in ("%filen%") do (
   (echo(%%a>%%a)
)
```

Comment: thisone quite works but the files have no content ( line 1 should be the content of file1.txt, line 2 the content of file2.txt)... other ideas? thanks so much guys,  Anita

Comment: @diva - shall be tested and fixed.